# Shell script fails for large number of files in directory

Tags: bash, sh

os: aix, shell: bsh

I have about 20k of files in a directory and those files are named filename.pdf.marker and filename.pdf, we copy the directory content with the following snippet

```
ls ${WORKING_DIR}/*.pdf.marker 2> /dev/null | while read FILEMARKER;
do
    FILENAME=${WORKING_DIR}/$(basename ${FILEMARKER} .marker)
        mv ${FILENAME} ${LOG_DIR}/.  
        mv ${FILENAME}.marker ${LOG_DIR}/.  
    done
```

But the catch is that not all files are copied because **ls** doesn't return the complete file list in the working directory, because the file list is too long.

Could you give me some advice how to upgrade the script without removing the loop?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a shell glob instead. For example:

```
for file in ${WORKING_DIR}/*.pdf.marker; do
    : # do something with "$file"
done
```

Comment: It will be likely even worse, as shell globs usually read the whole list into memory

Comment: which is generally better than doing it lazily through a pipe, which is even more unpredictable and error-prone than co-routines. 20000 filenames will be roughly <1M of memory which is acceptable given that this is an extreme case.

Comment: +1 for the only correct post. (But better quote the `${WORKING_DIR}`).

Comment: @JoSo Agree that quoting is important, but it's a side issue for the problem at hand. (Un)quoting a glob can be ugly business; the best solution is often something more like `cd "$WORKING_DIR"; for file in *marker; do :; done`. Same idea, but it avoids quoting issues with more complex glob patterns than what the OP is dealing with here (e.g. `foo*bar*.*.baz`). Thanks for reminding folks to always keep an eye on defensive coding techniques!

Comment: @CodeGnome: You can simply do `"$WORKING_DIR"/*.pdf.marker`, there's no issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `find` instead of `ls`:

```
find ${WORKING_DIR} -name \*.pdf.marker | while read FILENAME; do
  ...
done
```

I'm intentionally ignoring the possibility of spaces in file names, to keep things simple.

Comment: This suffers from the same problems as the OP has: Too many arguments to the find command. What you wanted was `-name \*.pdf.marker` to prevent the argument being interpreted as glob and expanded to 20000 arguments. Furthermore slightly incorrect in other ways as you had indicated (no need to do it "simple" there are even simpler ways which are correct on top)

Answer (score 0):

I Don't want to steal the correct answer kudos from CodeGnome, but make clear what happens: `ls "$WORKING_DIR"/*.pdf.marker` results in the shell forking of a new process with process image `ls` provided with #num_matching_files arguments (unlike on Windows, where every command has to include its own globbing code, on Unix the glob is expanded by the **shell** before the command is even called).

Most if not all systems have limitations as to the length of the commandline / number of arguments and you just hit a hard wall here (because in your case #num_matching_files is 20000)

Answer (score -1):

globs fail if the filelist is too long.  Instead of the glob, filter the result:

```
ls ${WORKING_DIR} | grep '\.pdf\.marker$'  | while read FILEMARKER
do
    ...
done
```

The obligatory disclaimer:  this will fail if your filenames contain special characters such as any whitespace.

Comment: -1 Why do you keep claiming that globs could ever fail without giving an argument? I no one spec I could find an indication of that, and no one but you claims it. I have just tested with 1.000.000 files both in a tmpfs and an ext3 directory, works like a charm. Try `mkdir testdir ; cd testdir; for i in \`seq 1000\` ; do touch \`seq "$((i-1))"000 "$i"000\` ; done ; time for i in * ; do echo "$i" ; done | wc -l` (you have to 1000 times touch 1000 files because for 1 time 1000000 files: argument list too long on my system)

Comment: @JoSo Because I have seen it happen.  Why do you insist on denying that globs can fail?

Comment: @JoSo  It is entirely possible that modern shells on modern systems perform substantially better than in the past.  However, as recently as 2005, I have seen csh scripts with `for i in *` fail with `glob failed` errors on as few as 200000 files.  I do not recall seeing it in a bourne shell.   Perhaps it was merely a csh error.

Comment: Guess what, I already did, and there is nothing indicating that a glob could fail. (Only some perl code which errors out "glob failed" because probably no file matched. But we are not talking about perl and everybody knows that any kind of a glob can fail **to match**). Also, no specification allows for an error. Also, it works for me with **1000.000** files. Please reproduce the error you claim to exist, and give the shell code, I will tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-05/msg00266.html means that no **file matched**. In this case the glob will expand to itself (unless `shopt -s nullglob` in bash), and `ls` will tell you that there is no such file. We know that this can happen. This has nothing to do with what you claim.

Comment: @JoSo It's not a csh issue.  It is a memory issue.  On a modern system with a decent amount of memory, it is not likely for the glob to fail.  If memory is tight, the shell simply cannot load the entire file list into memory and has no choice but to abort.  The error in that case is usually reported a `glob failed`.  It is entirely possible that you have the luxury of working in environments where you never run short of memory, and perhaps this is an issue that can be safely ignored on modern hosted systems.  But it is silly for you to deny that it can ever be an issue.

Comment: @JoSo, you miss the point of the link.  You claimed above that I am the only person claiming that globs can fail.  In that link, David Korn is making the claim as well.

Comment: No, what you are claiming is: "globs as used in `sh` can fail for large amounts of matching filenames (even before the system runs out of memory after 23423623466289462346982346 matched files)". What Dave Korn claims in this one old post that you struggled to find is "your glob did not match any files, just because the file you expected to be there was in fact not". (He does this by using the same word as you "failed" which is not entirely wrong but means something entirely different)

Comment: @JoSo where did I ever claim that the glob can fail before the system runs out of memory?  I have claimed that globs can fail, and I've seen it happen.  I suspect the reason they fail is lack of memory, but I don't really care about the reason.  I distrust them because I've seen them fail.  You seem to think they can never fail.

Comment: Everything can fail because of memory shortage, as I now wrote the 5th time or so. Is anyone surprised? The fact that you did not stop telling everybody to not use globs (which **is the only correct way to do it in shell**) even after the 3rd or 4th time that that obvious fact was on the table, indicates that you thought it could fail after a fixed number independent of the amount of system memory. Now if you honestly want to claim that any script you executed failed because the system couldn't hold all matching filenames at once then you must be kidding.

Comment: @JoSo As I've repeatedly said, I do not know whether scripts that failed 7 years ago with the error `glob failed`  failed because of memory constraints or some other reason.  I do know that reading the entire file list into memory is often unnecessary, only necessary if filenames with newlines and other special characters are allowed.  I also know that globs can fail, so I avoid them and encourage others to do so.  If you write the script with a glob, it can fail.  If you write it with a while loop, it can fail if your filenames contain newlines.  I consider the glob failure more problematic.

Comment: So you wanted me to google "glob failed" to learn that system memory is limited? You must be kidding. And, let's do a calculation: 20.000 with average 20 characters is 400k of memory. which is 20% of what only a running bash uses (2M). That implies I should also run no commands with the shell (not to think of pipelines) because those usually need 1-10M. Man. Stop. That. Crap. Do it correctly. Please don't respond now, it's hilarious.

Answer (score -2):

Try to switch off the sorting for `ls` (`-f` or `-U`, I think), or use another program like `find`

Comment: The problem is not `ls` itself, but the fact that `ls` is called with 20000 arguments which is too much depending on the system.